# Wordpress Custom Page CSS issue for IE9

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

The webpage is http://www.parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus/ It is displaying correctly on all browsers except IE9. The CSS is:

```
#primary { display: -webkit-box; 
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex; }
```

The conditional css for ie 7 and ie 8 is:

```
.ie8 .content-area1{
width: 70%;
display: inline-block; }
.ie7 .content-area1{
width: 70%;
display: inline-block; }
```

There is no conditional css file for IE9. So, please suggest the code which I can put in style.css so that the page also displays correctly for IE9. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 and doesn't support flexbox ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for full browser support details), so you'll need to use something like your IE7/8 alternative layout for IE9.

You can work without having a conditional CSS for IE9 in one of several ways:

- Use CSS's override mechanisms. Simply specify `display:inline-block` above `display:flex` (etc) inside the same selector, and every browser will pick the last defined option that they support. So if `flex` is below `inline-block`, IE9 will use `inline-block` because it doesn't understand `flex`, and others will use `flex` because they do know it and it's below `inline-block`. Sure, this doesn't deal with setting the `width`, but we've got half the problem solved without any browser-specific code at all (in fact, this would work for IE7/8 too, so you can reduce your specific code for them as well). `width` might be solvable with a similar trick by specifying a default value using a measurement unit not support in older browsers like `rem` or `vmin` or something, and then overridding it with `%` for the older browsers, but whether that would work for you would depend on your actual layout.
- Use a library such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will add feature support flags that you can use in the form of class names on your `<body>` tag. For example, it will add a `flexbox` class for browsers that support it, and a `no-flexblox` class for those that don't. This means you can write CSS code that targets browsers that support the feature or not -- eg:

  .flexbox #primary {
      display:flex; //etc...
  }
  .no-flexbox #primary {
      display:inline-block;
      width:70%;
  }
- Use a browser hack. I really don't like suggesting this, but it is an option. There are CSS hacks that specifically target IE9 if you really want to use them. I won't repeat them here though as I don't think it's the best option. If you want to use them, Google will tell you what you need to know.
- Use an IE9-specific class just as you are currently for IE7 and IE8. You're doing it already, so it doesn't seem like it should be too much of a stretch.
- Just use `inline-block` across the board. If the `inline-block` layout works, why not just use that. Flexbox is great, but if you need IE7/8/9 support, you're not going to be able to use it consistently, so....?

Personally, I'd go with the Modernizr solution. It solves this problem very neatly, and can also deal with most other cases where you might consider having browser-specific styles due to missing features.

Comment: Hi..thanks. its fixed for IE9 now. But, I noticed there is an issue with IE10. The main content is overlapping with sidebar links. Please advice.

Comment: You can check it by entering URL http://www.parentcenterhub.org/region6-aboutus/ at http://netrenderer.com/index.php for IE10